# jqGrid on App Engine not rendering results when run from non local host !

Tags: google-app-engine, jqgrid

wondering anyone else encountered this problem before - jqGrid works fine when working on my Google Appengine application on local machine (using eclipse+local datastore). When the same the application is deployed to actual domain, although the ajax data calls (i'm using XML format) are returning correct values (as confirmed using firebug ), the returned information does not appear as rows in the grid table. (Both firebug console and firefox error console shows same messages for both local and deployed requests).

Any helpful pointers ??

Answer (score 0):

Solved !
I had not explicitly set the content-type as "text/xml" when returning data, so the XML data was still having the default header "text/html". This somehow was ignored when the data was served from local host.
Setting this header solved the issue.

Thanks.